# tc-angular-chartjs doesn't appear at loading

Tags: angularjs

I have a line chart which doesn't appears at the loading of the page but only appears on hover, it's very strange. I thought I had forgotten some options but i also paste the code of the web site http://carlcraig.github.io/tc-angular-chartjs/line/ in my programm. I still have the problem... 
any ideas please?

Comment: post your code or recreate a problem using jsfiddle

Comment: Well, my code didn't have any problem, It was a bug with the version of charts.js i was using. It doesn't matter any more, I have found another library which suits perfectly my datas(highcharts). Thank you for your quick reply.